# Using htaccess to redirect correctly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, sitemap, robots.txt, google-crawlers

I am working with `robots.txt`, `sitemap.xml` and `.htaccess` in my project by now and I get accessing errors for my sitemap.xml url's, if I submit them in the Google Webmaster Tools.

**robots.txt**

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow:
```

**sitemap.xml**

```
<url>
  <loc>http://www.example.de/</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.example.de/blog/article/</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.exampe.de/blog/article/example-article</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)blog/article/$ $1article.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)blog/article/example-article$ $1blog/example-article.php
```

**My folder structure:**

```
├───blog
│   └─── example-article.php
├─── sitemap.xml
├─── robots.txt
├─── .htaccess
├─── article.php
├─── ...
```

Google Webmaster Tools say:

```
http://www.example.de/blog/article/
http://www.example.de/blog/article/example-article
```

get blocked by robots.txt, which is not possible due the fact I allowed to crawl everything.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Maybe it's because your robots.txt is blocking it. Your robots.txt doesn't look right.

Comment: Yeah, its fact that it gets blocked by the robots.txt. But where exactly are the mistakes? Can't I use the mod_rewrited urls in the robots? Because I want them to be indexed like that.

Answer (score 2):

Use: **robots.txt**

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /only_folder_name_you_disallow/
```

You can't use `Allow`

Note also that globbing and regular expression are not supported in either the User-agent or Disallow lines. The '*' in the User-agent field is a special value meaning "any robot". Specifically, you cannot have lines like "User-agent: *bot*", "Disallow: /tmp/*" or "Disallow: *.gif".
http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it. What is the reason, I can't use "Allow"? I've seen this very often. Or does it just don't work in my case?

Comment: I modified the robots.txt for testing purposes to restrict nothing: User-Agent: * Disallow:
I get the same errors so the problem isn't the robots.txt, .htaccess or sitemap.xml are wrong, but I bet on the .htaccess. Do you see the error cause?

Comment: "Allow" is not in the Robots Exclusion Protocol. Even if some robots use it. But Allow one folder and after Disallow all, is not even clear to me. In your htaccess, you rewrite links with `blog...` it's not the case for `robots.txt` and not the problem. You wrote Google say `robots.txt`... Test again your `robots.txt` with Google Webmaster Tools. And your `sitemap.xml`...

Comment: I changed the robots (> 24 h ago) and I get the same errors, although I could "Fetch as Google" the URLs, which are in my sitemap, and they got indexed, after I "send [the URLs] to the index". I still get warnings that the URLs aren't crawlable. Any help?

Comment: Nothing in your html code ? `ex: <meta name="robots"`

Comment: The problem wasn't my code. It was caused by Google, caching and working with a old robots.txt.